# How can I show validation loss and validation accuracy evaluation for the detectron2 model?

Tags: python, metrics, image-segmentation, loss-function, detectron

I have split the data to train and test (0.85)

and here's my loss visualization code :

```
import pandas as pd
metrics_df = pd.read_json("./output/metrics.json", orient="records", lines=True)
mdf = metrics_df.sort_values("iteration")
mdf.head(10).T
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mdf1 = mdf[~mdf["total_loss"].isna()]
ax.plot(mdf1["iteration"], mdf1["total_loss"], c="C0", label="train")
if "validation_loss" in mdf.columns:
    mdf2 = mdf[~mdf["validation_loss"].isna()]
    ax.plot(mdf2["iteration"], mdf2["validation_loss"], c="C1", label="validation")
# ax.set_ylim([0, 0.5])
ax.legend()
ax.set_title("Loss curve")
plt.show()
```

---

How would I include that `validation_loss` column in my metrics file?

My outputs are like this :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get the validation loss written into the *metrics.json* file is to add a hook to the trainer that calculates the loss on the validation set during training.

I have successfully used the `LossEvalHook` class from [here](https://gist.github.com/ortegatron/c0dad15e49c2b74de8bb09a5615d9f6b#file-lossevalhook-py) in my work.

The example code below shows how to use it to create a custom trainer containing a hook for calculating the validation loss every 100 iterations. This code assumes that the validation set is registered and is passed via the `cfg.DATASETS.TEST` config parameter.

Also, note that the hook that writes to the *metrics.json* file is the last element in the [list of hooks returned by the `DefaultTrainer.build_hooks` method](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/0b500b4d7ed11e9728867298f5f168fb34908e2c/detectron2/engine/defaults.py#L362). In order to get the validation loss to also be written into the file, the hook is inserted before the writer hook in the code below.

```
from detectron2.data import DatasetMapper, build_detection_test_loader
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer
from LossEvalHook import LossEvalHook 

class CustomTrainer(DefaultTrainer):
    """
    Custom Trainer deriving from the "DefaultTrainer"

    Overloads build_hooks to add a hook to calculate loss on the test set during training.
    """

    def build_hooks(self):
        hooks = super().build_hooks()
        hooks.insert(-1, LossEvalHook(
            100, # Frequency of calculation - every 100 iterations here
            self.model,
            build_detection_test_loader(
                self.cfg,
                self.cfg.DATASETS.TEST[0],
                DatasetMapper(self.cfg, True)
            )
        ))

        return hooks
```

The custom trainer can then be used for training instead of the `DefaultTrainer`.

```
trainer = CustomTrainer(cfg)
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Thank you @zepman , but I have a question, it validates only on the **1st test** document every 100 iterations ?

Comment: No, it uses the entire test dataset that is registered. There is a 0 index used when getting the test set name because [`cfg.DATASETS.TEST` is a tuple](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/config.html#:~:text=DatasetCatalog%0A_C.-,DATASETS,-.TEST%20%3D), which allows multiple registered test datasets to be passed via the config. 
So, when you have only one test set (which is typical), e.g., `"my_testset"` that is registered, it has to be set in the config as `cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("my_testset", )`.